# Passing data between components in React

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Ultimately I'm trying to pass mapped elements in an array to a child component. I made a WordPress API call to get back posts for a preview page, and now that I'm trying to have that data render in their own pages, I keep getting that the data is undefined. The dynamic links are rendering as expected, but none of the other data is being passed.

Articles.js

```
// cut for brevity
  render() {

    let articles = this.state.newsData.map((article, index) => {
      if(this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>
      if(!this.state.newsData) return <p>Loading...</p> 
      return(
        <div key={index} className="article-container">

          <div className="article-preview">
          <span className="article-date">{article.date}</span>
          <h5>{article.title.rendered}</h5>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.excerpt.rendered }} />

          <Link to={`/news/${article.slug}`}>Read More...</Link>

          </div>
          <Route path={`/news/:articleSlug`}
            render={ props => <Article data={article} {...props} />} 
            />
        </div>

      )
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>All Articles from Blog</h3>
        {articles}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Article.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Article = ({match, data}) => {
  let articleData;
  { console.log(this.data) }

  if(data)
    articleData = <div>
      <h3> {data.title.rendered}</h3>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content.rendered }} />
      <hr />
    </div>

  else 
    articleData = <h2> Sorry. That article doesn't exist. </h2>;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {articleData}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Article;
```

How do I get the data from the array into the Article component?

Comment: `{ console.log(this.data) }` is incorrect. It should be `console.log(data) `

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks for the catch. `console.log(data)` still returns undefined, though.

Comment: You might change the order of `data={article} {...props}` to see `{...props} data={article}` and check, it might happen that props contains a variable data and hence you data props is getting overriden

Comment: For the one who downvoted the question can you please explain what is wrong with it so the user can improve next time?

Comment: I see this question fairly often on SO, and I think most of the time the users want to be pointed in the direction of Redux.  In a certain sense that's one of the main problems it solves, it provides a mechanism to share information between components all over the application: https://redux.js.org/ It makes what you are attempting to do so much easier, I couldn't imagine coding a complex react app without it.

Comment: @brub thanks -- I'll check Redux out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with asynchronous requests.

You have a `route` that will call the `render` method when the user clicks on a link. At that point in time, javascript has no reference to the `article` anymore, you need to persist it.

Here's an example of what you are experiencing

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1);
}
```

The code above will always log 10

A solution to this problem is using `bind`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) { console.log(i); }.bind(null, i), 1);
}
```

So, in your code, you need to persist the `article` variable.

You can do that by calling a method that takes the `data`.

```
  renderArticle(data) {
    return props => <Article data={data} {...props} />
  }

  render() {

    let articles = this.state.newsData.map((article, index) => {
      if(this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>
      if(!this.state.newsData) return <p>Loading...</p> 
      return(
        <div key={index} className="article-container">

          <div className="article-preview">
          <span className="article-date">{article.date}</span>
          <h5>{article.title.rendered}</h5>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.excerpt.rendered }} />

          <Link to={`/news/${article.slug}`}>Read More...</Link>

          </div>
          <Route path={`/news/:articleSlug`}
            render={this.renderArticle(article)} 
            />
        </div>

      )
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>All Articles from Blog</h3>
        {articles}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the push in the right direction, I still have more tweaking to do, but I think I understand better what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Even with this new method that should be persisting the data, once the new component is loaded and rendered after clicking the link, the data array is still undefined... Is it because the renderArticle method is declared before the data is mapped?